# Не работает повторное нажатие на выделенную ветку TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

```
<TreeView 
    TreeViewItem.Selected="TreeViewItem_SelectedItem__b"
    TreeViewItem.MouseLeftButtonDown="TreeViewItem_SelectedItem__b"
```

`TreeViewItem.MouseLeftButtonDown` - Если ветка уже была выбрана, то при нажатии ничего не происходит.

```
public void TreeViewItem_SelectedItem__b(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var node = (Node)tw_tree_b.SelectedItem;

            .


            ////
            TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
            if (item != null)
            {
                ...
            }

        }
```

Добавлено

```
<TreeView 
    TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewItem_Expanded"
TreeViewItem.Selected="TreeViewItem_SelectedItem__b"
SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged__b"
```

Не происходит вхождения в эту функцию, при нажатии уже на выделенный узел:

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged__b(object sender,  RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e)
    {
        //Perform actions when SelectedItem changes
        //MessageBox.Show(((TreeViewItem)e.NewValue).Header.ToString());
        TreeViewItem_SelectedItem__b(sender, e);
    }
```

Comment: Какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: Повторно запустить ту же функцию при повторном нажатии на тот же узел дерева

Comment: Вообще не входит в метод или не выполняет то,  что в нем написано?  Покажите код самого метода пож-ста.

Comment: не входит в метод

Comment: В `TreeViewItem_SelectedItem__b(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` входит только при первом нажатии пока узел не выделен. При втором нажатии уже на выделенный узел - не входит.

Comment: При поторном нажатии TreeView_SelectedItemChanged событие не сработает, т.к. выбранный элемент не изменился. Используйте другое событие к примеру Click.

Answer (score 0):

Event называется: `<TreeView 
SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged"/>`

Comment: Не помогло.....

Comment: не входит потому, что выбранный элемент не изменился

Comment: Вы пробывали использовать GetFocus ?

Answer (score -1):

в обработке нажатия на `TreeViewItem` добавьте 
`IsSelected = false;`